# What are the Windows tar.gz files for the Java JRE (7, 8)?

Tags: java, windows, java-7

From what I can tell from the tests I did during the last hour, Oracle finally(*) included "xcopy style" packages for the Java JRE on Windows - even for the *non* server version.

And yes, I know what a gzipped tar file is. It's just that there is no documentation of these files -- vs. the executable installer for Windows *is* documented.

Looking at the [current Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html) or [8 download pages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) for the non-server JRE, I see:

- Windows x86 Online    jre-7u67-windows-i586-iftw.exe
- Windows x86 Offline   jre-7u67-windows-i586.exe
- **Windows x86         `jre-7u67-windows-i586.tar.gz`**
- Windows x64           jre-7u67-windows-x64.exe
- **Windows x64         jre-7u67-windows-x64.tar.gz**

These zipped files don't appear to be mentioned in any docs I could google up, yet their purpose seems to be to not have to run any installer, just copy them to a machine, set up the path(s) correctly, and run them. (and run it does, I tested that).

Still, no mention or docs at all seems odd. So is there any official mentioning of the introduction of these `tar.gz` files for Windows?  As far as I can tell from the [historical downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jre-7u7-oth-JPR), they were introduced in [J7u9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u9-relnotes-1863279.html) - and for Java 8 apparently with 8u20.

---

<sub>(*) "finally" is relative ... J7u9 is from 2012-10-16, so it's really not recent, but I only now start to look into getting J6 stuff to run on J7 / J8, so it's nice to see those now.</sub>

Comment: Whats the problem? It's a [gzipped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) file containing the JRE.

Comment: Those are installer-free (aka "portable") versions of the JRE. Just unzip them and you can use them.

Comment: Note they've also started doing this for 8u20, couldn't find tar.gz for 8u11 though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I figured as much - it's just, see question, odd that there is zero official (I could find) information wrt. these files. (Or, rather, I couldn't find *any* information, like, any blog entry where someone wrote: "Hey cool, now we have installer free versions." nothing. I find that odd. Therefore this question to have *something* for future reference :-)

Comment: I have done PrivateJRE.zip "installs" since Java1.4, app is using c:/myapp/jre/* virtual machine. I installed regular java-setup.exe on one development machine then took destination folder to be put inside application.

Comment: I can't find any "official" documentation or mentioning for the other files on the download page either.

Comment: I found it.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle documentation that describes how to install these `tar.gz` files (in the Java 8 case) is:

- [Server JRE Installation for Microsoft Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_server_jre.html#CFHGHHFJ)

You basically un-gzip and un-tar one of these downloads and you have a Java JRE or JDK installation.  All you need to do then is configure your Java application to use it ... in the appropriate fashion.

(Obviously, this is a Server installation.  It isn't registered in the Windows registry and doesn't have auto-update or uninstall functionality.)

The above page is referenced from the [Java 8 SE Installation Instructions Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html?xd_co_f=37c726a5-28fb-438d-8775-4783af7946cb) page.